# How can I create an immutable array?

Tags: powershell

I want to create an (immutable) tuple (or array) of elements in Powershell, so my attempt is the following:

```
$t = @("A","B")
```

Now, this creates an array that I can add to:

```
$t += "C"
```

I want `$t` to be immutable during the execution of the program. How can I do this?

Comment: @Snak3d0c if you can change it; it's not immutable.

Comment: Seems i misread the explanation i found. Thanks for clearing that up. I deleted my comment so that i don't confuse others.

Answer (score 6):

You could actually use tuples

```
PS[1] (203) > $t = [tuple]::create(1,2,3)
PS[1] (204) > $t.item1
1
PS[1] (205) > $t.item1 = 4
'item1' is a ReadOnly property.
At line:1 char:1
+ $t.item1 = 4
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Comment: This is great. I'm sorry to see that tuples are kind of a second class citizen and don't get all the properties and methods that come built in for something like an array but still nice to know.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `Read-Only` or `Constant` variables: (`Read-Only` variables *can* be modified using `-Force` switch with `Set-Variable` method)

```
New-Variable -Name foo -Option Constant -Value @("A", "B")
$foo += "C"
Cannot overwrite variable foo because it is read-only or constant.
```

Comment: That's not immutable. This gives no error: $foo[0] = "C"

Comment: You'd need to make each value in it a constant as well, but this could work. Using actual tuples as bruce's answer shows is probably better.

Comment: This is akin to applying the [`readonly` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) to a field in C#: the variable itself is read-only but not necessarily the object it references.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell simply doesn't have the concept of immutability as I understand it. You can fake it with custom objects sort of. Here is some code that can be used to fake an immutable hash table:

```
function New-ImmutableObject($object) {
    $immutable = New-Object PSObject

    $object.Keys | %{ 
        $value = $object[$_]
        $closure = { $value }.GetNewClosure()
        $immutable | Add-Member -name $_ -memberType ScriptProperty -value $closure
    }

    return $immutable
}
$immutable = New-ImmutableObject @{ Name = "test"}
$immutable.Name = "test1" # Throws error
```

Not my code. It comes from this quite nice article [Functional Programming in PowerShell](http://alexfalkowski.blogspot.com/2012/08/functionalprogramming-in-powershell.html)

You should be able to extend this to whatever type of object you want.