# How to create Readonly array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, readonly

I have some read-only variables set with `Set-Variable myVar -Value 10 -Option ReadOnly` syntax but I need read-only arrays too. How do I make read-only arrays?

Thanks

Comment: `[Array]::AsReadOnly`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an immutable array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916749/how-can-i-create-an-immutable-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as countless times before, has provided the solution in a terse comment on the question; he's also helped to improve this answer:
**Use [`[Array]::AsReadOnly($someArray)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_AsReadOnly__1___0___)**, available in **PSv3+**<sup>[1]</sup>
:

```
# Create a 2-element read-only collection containing strings.
$readOnlyColl = [Array]::AsReadOnly(('one', 'two'))

# Try to modify an element, which now fails:
$readOnlyColl[0] = 'uno'
```

In **PSv2**, use a cast to `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[<type>]]`, as shown below.

The above yields the following, demonstrating that elements cannot be modified:

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.String].
```

Note that the error message is somewhat misleading, because it is only *write* access via indexing that isn't allowed, *read* access (e.g., `$readOnlyColl[0]`) works just fine.

While **`$readOnlyColl` is not strictly an *array*, it behaves like one**
 for all practical purposes.
Technically, `$readOnlyColl` is an instance of generic type `` System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1 `` using an **element type inferred from the input array's elements**.<sup>[2]</sup>
**Caveat**: The **return collection is only a *wrapper* around an array** and, depending on the specific input array and casts you apply, later modifications to the input array's elements could be reflected in the wrapper collection.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

If you want to **control the elements' data type *explicitly***, use a *cast*.

E.g., to create a `[string]`-typed collection from `[int]` values:

```
# Cast to an array of the desired type first.
[Array]::AsReadOnly([string[]] (1, 2, 3)

# Alternatively, cast to the target collection type directly.
# Always use this in PSv2, where [Array]::AsReadOnly() cannot be called.
[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[string]] (1, 2, 3)
```

Use `[object[]]` / `[object]` for `[object]`-typed elements, as with regular PowerShell arrays, but note that if the input array is indeed already an `[object[]]` array, the resulting collection will be a *wrapper* around the array - see footnote [2].

---

Just to spell out **why `Set-Variable myVar -Option ReadOnly` is *not* enough to create a read-only *array***: it makes the *variable* read-only, meaning that you cannot assign a different value to *it*; by contrast, modifying a *property of the data* that happens to be stored in the variable - such as an array's element - is not prevented.

---

<sup>[1] The method has been available since .NET v2, on which PSv2 is built; however, only PSv3 introduced the ability to call *generic* methods directly, so PSv3+ is required; however, in PSv2 you can cast to `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[<type>]]` directly.</sup>

<sup>[2] That is, even though PowerShell creates `[object[]]` arrays by default, if the actual elements happen to be all of the same type, PowerShell chooses that specific type rather than `[object]`; in the case at hand, because both elements of the input array were *strings*, a new `[string[]` typed array was created behind the scenes, which the resulting read-only collection *wraps* as type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[string]]`.</sup>

<sup>[3] Because the collection is only a *wrapper* around the input array, anyone with access to the input array could still modify its elements and the wrapper collection would reflect that change.

In *PowerShell*, however, you're often shielded from this potential problem *if* PowerShell happens to create a *new* array behind the scenes that it then passes to `[Array]::AsReadOnly()`. A new array is created for PS arrays (`[object[]]`) whose elements all happen to have the same type, assuming you don't explicitly cast such an array to `[object[]]` in the `[Array]::AsReadOnly()` call. For a specifically typed input array (e.g., `[int[]]`), a new array is only created if you cast to a *different* type (e.g., `[string[]]`); demonstration of the wrapper problem if *no* new array is created:

`$arr = [int[]] (1..3); $coll = [Array]::AsReadOnly($arr); $arr[1] = 42; $coll[1]` 
- `$coll[1]` now reflects `42`, i.e., the *changed* value that was assigned via the underlying array, `$a`.</sup>

Comment: One thing to be aware of: `ReadOnlyCollection` is a wrapper not a copy. So, unless PowerShell does the copy, `ReadOnlyCollection` is connected to original array: `$a = 1..3; $b = [Array]::AsReadOnly([object[]]$a); $b[1]; $a[1] = 42; $b[1]`. Also, one interesting thing: it is enough to wrap array into `Collection` for it to be read-only: `([System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[object]] (1, 2, 3)).IsReadOnly`.

Comment: Thanks for the wrapper info, @PetSerAl: I've added it to the answer, which I've also restructured slightly.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Re `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[object]]` being enough to make the collection read-only. That is not only surprising, but also seems undesirable - a bug? Note that `.IsReadOnly`, stemming from the `ICollection<T>` interface, only indicates that the collection as a whole is read-only, it makes no guarantees regarding the mutability of its _elements_. `Get-Member` shows the `.Item` property as settable: `Item           ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int index) {get;set;}`. Do you have an explanation.

Comment: `Get-Member` only report that there is a setter, because `Collection` have element setter. But that setter can just [throw an exception](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,50) instead of setting the element. It was good Connect issue describing this behavior, but as Connect now gone, I can not link to it.

Comment: @PetSerAl: When you cast an array to `Collection<T>`, its generic `IList<T>` interface is wrapped.
However, [`Collection<T>`'s indexer explicitly prevents _set_ indexing attempts based on querying the `.IsReadOnly` property](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/ObjectModel/Collection.cs,49), which returns `$True` for arrays via the [`IList<T>` interface](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs,2568) (as opposed to [via the _non-generic_ `[IList]` interface](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs,576))

Comment: @PetSerAl: As an aside: I recently created an answer to a related question that I'd like your input on, if you're up for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51663135/45375