# How to copy array elements to ReadOnlyCollection?

Tags: powershell

I need to create a ReadOnlyCollection from elements of an array but it seems like ReadOnlyCollection elements can only be defined in declaration of the collection. Is there any other way than listing each element of the array in the declaration of the collection as in the following sample?

```
[byte[]]$arr=10,20,30
[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[byte]]$readOnly=
 $arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the array to the constructor instead:

```
$readOnly = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[byte]' -ArgumentList @(,$arr)
```

or (PowerShell 5.0 and up):

```
$readOnly = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[byte]]::new($arr)
```

---

Now, your question title specifically says *copy array elements* - beware while you won't be able to modify `$readOnly`, its contents will still reflect changes to the array that it's wrapping:

```
PS C:\> $arr[0] = 100
PS C:\> $arr[0]
100
PS C:\> $readOnly[0]
100
```

If you need a completely separate read-only collection, copy the array to another array first and then overwrite the variable reference with the read-only collection:

```
$readOnly = [byte[]]::new($arr.Count)
$arr.CopyTo($readOnly, 0)
$readOnly = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[byte]]::new($readOnly)
```

Now you can modify `$arr` without affecting `$readOnly`:

```
PS C:\> $arr[0] = 100
PS C:\> $arr[0]
100
PS C:\> $readOnly[0]
10
```

Comment: There's no need to copy since you can turn the array itself into the read-only collection while retaining all of the elements. Thanks

Comment: @bp2017 depends on context, if you're taking an array as a non-pipelined parameter argument in a function you can't know that that's the only reference to it for example :)

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51920127/45375) contains good alternatives and background information, but in your case you can **simply *assign* your array to your type-constrained `$readOnly` variabl**e:

```
[byte[]] $arr=10,20,30 
[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[byte]] $readOnly = $arr
```

In PSv3+ you can alternatively use `[Array]::AsReadOnly()`:

```
[byte[]] $arr=10,20,30 
$readOnly = [Array]::AsReadOnly($arr) # shorter, but doesn't lock in the type of $readOnly
```

As stated, `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>` only *wraps* its input array, so later changes to the input array's elements would be reflected in the read-only collection.

However, whether it wraps your actual *input* array, depends on its specific type, because Powershell may create a *new* array for you behind the scenes - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864487/45375) for details.

If in doubt, use `$arr.Clone()` to explicitly create a copy of your array.